# Put Several Select Statements into Different Columns with Group BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table, for simplicity I included only 1 customer name, it has many

```
+--------------+---------------------+---------------+
| customername | customercontactname | statename     |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------+
| IKEA         | Sam                 | Won           |
| IKEA         | Sam                 | Won           |
| IKEA         | Sam                 | Won           |
| IKEA         | Sara                | Won           |
| IKEA         | Sara                | Won           |
| IKEA         | Sara                | Won           |
| IKEA         | Sara                | Won           |
| IKEA         | Amelia              | Lost          |
| IKEA         | Maya                | Won           |
| IKEA         | Maya                | Won           |
+--------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

I want this output

```
+--------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
| customername | customercontactname | WonOpps | LostOpps |
+--------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
| IKEA         | Sam                 | 3       | NULL     |
| IKEA         | Sara                | 4       | NULL     |
| IKEA         | Maya                | 2       | NULL     |
| IKEA         | Amelia              | NULL    | 1        |
+--------------+---------------------+---------+----------+
```

Trial (the result is fine for the first 3 rows, however Amelia is not showing in my final output):

```
SELECT t1.customername, 
       t1.customercontactname, 
       t1.wonopps, 
       t2.lostopps 
FROM   (SELECT customername, 
               customercontactname, 
               Count(*) AS WonOpps 
        FROM   mytable 
        WHERE  statename = 'won' 
        GROUP  BY customername, 
                  customercontactname) t1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT customername, 
                         customercontactname, 
                         Count(*) AS LostOpps 
                  FROM   mytable 
                  WHERE  statename = 'lost' 
                  GROUP  BY customername, 
                            customercontactname) t2 
              ON t1.customername = t2.customername 
                 AND t1.customercontactname = t2.customercontactname
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
   select customername, customercontactname, count(case when statename='Won' then 1 end ) WonOpps,
   count(case when statename='Lost' then 1 end ) WonLost
   from tablename
   group by customername, customercontactname
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sum`

```
 with t1 as
     (
       select customername,
       customercontactname,
       sum(case when statename='won' then 1 else 0 end ) as WonOpps,
       sum(case when statename='loss' then 1 else 0 end ) as LostOpps
       from t
       group by customername, customercontactname
) select customername,customercontactname, case when WonOpps>1 then WonOpps else null end as WonOpps,
case when LostOpps>1 then LostOpps else LostOpps end as LostOpps from t1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` combined with `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT    customername,
          customercontactname,
          SUM(CASE WHEN statename = 'Won'  THEN 1 END) AS WonOpps,
          SUM(CASE WHEN statename = 'Lost' THEN 1 END) AS WonLost
FROM      mytable
GROUP BY  customername, customercontactname
```

`SUM` returns `NULL` if no records match because we do not specify `ELSE`-values.

If you prefer to see `0` instead, then you can add `ELSE 0`, or you can use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query is not giving row for 'Amelia' is because you are using LEFT JOIN and because Amelia has not any 'won' value in statename column so its null on left side of join. Just to explain concept well, I am giving a simple solution.

1. write a left join query. It will give you all WonOpps. (your current query)
2. write a right join query. It will give you all LossOpps.
3. Union both above 2 queries.

See following query:

```
select a.customername, a.customercontactname, a.WonOpps, b.LostOpps from
(select customername,customercontactname, count(*) as WonOpps from mytable WHERE  statename = 'won' group by customername,customercontactname) a
 left join
(select customername,customercontactname, count(*) as LostOpps from mytable WHERE  statename = 'lost' group by customername,customercontactname) b
on a.customername = b.customername and a.customercontactname = b.customercontactname 
UNION ALL 
select d.customername, d.customercontactname, c.WonOpps, d.LostOpps  from
(select customername,customercontactname, count(*) as WonOpps from mytable WHERE  statename = 'won' group by customername,customercontactname) c
 right join
(select customername,customercontactname, count(*) as LostOpps from mytable WHERE  statename = 'lost' group by customername,customercontactname) d
on c.customername = d.customername and c.customercontactname = d.customercontactname ;
```

You may use many other options like sum, count, case to write a shorter query but this query will help you to understand the concept on top of your current work.